# Loop through table and save its content

Tags: javascript

I'm reading an Excel file in javascript.

One of the cell has a `VLOOKUP` formula:

```
VLOOKUP(C40,D107:F114,3,FALSE) //(searched value, table range, returned value column, exact match)
```

What it's basically doing is searching for the the value on `C40` in a table range of `D107 -> F114` (starting point and end point) and returning the value on the `3` column, on this example- column `F`. `FALSE` indicates we are looking for an exact match.

I need to extract the table defined on the formula `D107:F114` (`3` columns (`D`, `E`, `F`), `8` cells (`107`, `108`, `109`, etc.)) and save its content in code.

This is what I did- works fine, I am wondering if there is a shorter way to do it:

```
  const formula = sheet.cell('A40').formula()
  var splittedFormula = formula.split(/[\s,]+/) //split formula by params -> splittedFormula = [C40, D107:F114, 3, FALSE]
  const numOfColumns = splittedFormula[2] //geting the total number of columns by the third param- "returned value column" -> numOfColumns = 3
  let numOfCells = splittedFormula[1].split(/[\s:]+/) //get the start point of the table -> numOfCells = [D107, F114]
  let startingCell = numOfCells[0].replace(/\D/g, '') //extract the starting cell -> startingCell = 107
  let startingColumn = numOfCells[0].replace(/\d+/g, '') //extract the starting column -> startingColumn = D
  numOfCells =
    numOfCells[1].replace(/\D/g, '') - numOfCells[0].replace(/\D/g, '') + 1 //calculate how many cells on each column by substracting the start point cell from the end point cell (`114 - 107`) -> numOfCells = 8
  var table = new Array(numOfColumns) //defining an array of arrays -> table = [3]
  let currentCell
  //loop through the table in the excel sheet and save it's content each column is an array that store the cells value. table = [3][8] 
  for (var i = 0; i < numOfColumns; i++) { //numOfColumns=3
    table[i] = new Array(numOfCells) //numOfCells=8
    currentCell = startingCell
    for (var j = 0; j < numOfCells; j++) {
      table[i][j] = sheet.cell(startingColumn + currentCell).value()
      currentCell = parseFloat(currentCell) + 1 //increment to the next cell i.e. 107 + 1 = 108 etc..
    }
    startingColumn = String.fromCharCode(startingColumn.charCodeAt() + 1) //increment to the next column i.e. D + 1 = F etc..
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain what this formula does specifically? An example of what data is inputted to which cells and the results and what cell displays it.

Comment: @zer00ne Please see my edited question. Thanks.

Comment: The 3rd parameter isn't clear to me: `returned value column` nor how the 4th parameter is implemented: `exact match`. Also, `exact match = false` should mean that the match isn't exact (grammatically at least).

Comment: @zer00ne the 4th param is : _return an Approximate or Exact match – indicated as 1/TRUE, or 0/FALSE_ . The 3rd param is: _the column number in the range containing the value to return_

Answer (score 1):

The first "minimization" (and most important one) is to check if your `sheet` instance allows to extract a slice (idem the submatrix or table you try to extract).

On a more generic way you can:

1. skip some lines about extracting the formula (or at least make it clearer)

```
let formula = 'D107:F114'
let [colStart, rowStart, colEnd, rowEnd] = formula.match(/([A-Z]+)(\d+):([A-Z]+)(\d+)/).slice(1);
//[ colStart='D', rowStart='107', colEnd='F', rowEnd='114' ]
rowStart = parseInt(rowStart);
rowEnd   = parseInt(rowEnd);
colStart = colStart.charCodeAt()-65;
colEnd   = colEnd.charCodeAt()-65;
```

note that here, you may have columns like AA or ZZ so you may want to adapt the transformation of `colStart` and `colEnd` accordingly

2. then use `map` instead of for loop

```
let table = Array(colEnd-colStart+1).fill(0).map((_, j)=>{
    return Array(rowEnd-rowStart+1).fill(0).map((_, i)=>{
        let col = colStart + j;
        let row = rowStart + i;
        return sheet.cell(String.fromCharCode(col+65)+row).value();
    })
})
```

Regarding AA or ZZ, below an algorithm to convert them back and forth to int, but once again probably rely on your library since it would have to parse your string anyway..

```js
let sheet = {
    cell(x){return {value(){return x}}}
}

//not used, but enough to handle single letters...
function toColIdx(s){
    return s.charCodeAt()-'A'.charCodeAt();
}

function idxToCol(idx){
    return String.fromCharCode(idx+'A'.charCodeAt())
}

let base = (function(){
    let idxToChar = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
    let charToIdx   = idxToChar.reduce((acc, f,i)=>(acc[f] = i+1, acc),{})
    //I have checked the identity of idxToCol == idxToCol(toColIdx(idxToCol)) up to 16384
    return {
        toColIdx(s){
            return s.split('')
                .reverse()
                .reduce((acc,c,i)=>acc+charToIdx[c]*Math.pow(26,i),0);
        },
        idxToCol(idx){
            if(idx==1)return 'A';
            let n = Math.ceil(Math.log(idx)/Math.log(26));
            s = '';
            for(let i = 0; i<n; ++i){
                let x = idx % 26;
                if(x != 0){
                    s = idxToChar[x-1] + s;
                    idx-=x;
                    idx /= 26;
                }else{
                    s = 'Z' + s;
                    idx-=26;
                    idx /= 26;
                    if(idx==0) return s;
                }
            }
            return s;
        }
    }
})();
function extract(sheet, formula){
    let [colStart, rowStart, colEnd, rowEnd] = formula.match(/([A-Z]+)(\d+):([A-Z]+)(\d+)/).slice(1);
    //[ colStart='D', rowStart='107', colEnd='F', rowEnd='114' ]
    rowStart = parseInt(rowStart);
    rowEnd   = parseInt(rowEnd);
    colStart = base.toColIdx(colStart)
    colEnd   = base.toColIdx(colEnd)
    return Array(colEnd-colStart+1).fill(0).map((_, j)=>{
        return Array(rowEnd-rowStart+1).fill(0).map((_, i)=>{
            let col = colStart + j;
            let row = rowStart + i;
            return sheet.cell(base.idxToCol(col)+row).value();
        })
    })   
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(extract(sheet, 'A107:D114'),null,2))
console.log(JSON.stringify(extract(sheet, 'BZ107:CA114'),null,2))
```