# How to implement a Permutations generator(or memoized function) for set of Alphabets(both lowercase and uppercase) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance

I am implementing a variable name generator where I don't have control over the number of variable names required and, figured, using a generator or memoized function is the way to go instead of creating a list of all the permutations and saving in the memory.

Basically, I want to create a function which yields all the permutations of `[a-z][A-Z]` in an **incremental** fashion. It should return a sequence like the following `{'a', 'b', ...,'z','aa','ab',....,'az', 'ba', .... 'aA',... 'aTr'...'ZZZ', ...'Z(*52)'}`

For now I have,

```js
function* varNameGenerator() {
  const all =
    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' + 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.toUpperCase();
  let prefix = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < all.length; j++) {
      yield prefix + all[j];
    }
    prefix += all[i];
  }
}
```

This helps to generate about `2705` results, as the output will be a sequence from the set `{'a', 'b', ...,'aa',...'aZ', 'aba','abb'....,'abZ','abca','abcb','abcc',...,'abcZ','abcda'...}` and so on. This is usable but the length of a variable name increases very fast(every 52 function calls).

So is there a implementation that can incrementally yield all the permutations of the alphabets with smallest length ones first?

Comment: I lack time for proper answer. This is like the excel column numbering. I somehow wrote the bijection between a number and its associated column [on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895802/loop-through-table-and-save-its-content/58899465#58899465). You could just increment an id in your generator, and get back its associated varname via the written bij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursive generators:

```js
     const ALPHABET = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' + 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.toUpperCase();

    function* nameGenerator(length = 30, prev = "") {
      if(length <= 0) {
        yield prev;
        return;
      }

      for (const char of ["", ...ALPHABET]) {
        yield* nameGenerator(length - 1, prev + char);
      }
    }
   
    const it = nameGenerator();

    for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      console.log(it.next().value);
```

How it works:

1. There are 30 recursive calls made, each of them adding a char to `prev` ("" in the first iteration):

   "" -> "" + "" -> ... -> "" + ... + ""
2. The upmost iterator yields that value back

   ```
                <-- ""
   ```

Then the most upper loop goes to the next char, "a", and yields that back, this happens with all chars:

```
                      -> "" + ... + "a"
                     <-- "a"
                     ...
                     -> "" + ... + "Z"
                     <--- "Z"
```

3. The loop is done, we step up one level and continue with the loop there, then step up back to the loop:

   ```
                    <-
       "" + ... + "a" -> "" + ... + "a" + "a"
                    <-- "aa" 
                    <-- "ab"
                    ....
                    <-- "aZ"
   ```

This goes on till we looped 30 times on the downmost level

Comment: Awesome! Can you explain what is happening? I am a bit confused as I had no idea that recursive generators were a thing.